# Mail Not working in laravel console command within handle function

Tags: laravel, email

I'm developing a new Laravel application. When I'm using mail to send messages via laravel schedule command, I'm getting the following error:

> Swift_TransportException with message 'Process could not be started
> [The system cannot find the path specified. ]

This is my Command file.
EmailReminder.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\ScheduleMeeting;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Modules\User\Emails\MentorEmailReminder;

class EmailReminder extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'reminder:emails';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send email notification to user about reminders.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $date = now()->tz('Asia/Singapore')->addDay(); // Current date is added one day
        $newDate = $date->format('Y-m-d g:i A');
         $tomorrow_meetings = ScheduleMeeting::where('start_time','=', $newDate)
                                                 ->where('status',1)
                                                 ->where('meeting_type',0)
                                                 ->get();

      
                                                
        $data = [];
        foreach($tomorrow_meetings as $meeting){
            $data[$meeting->mentor_id][] = $meeting->toArray();
        }
        
        foreach($data as $mentorId => $reminders){
            $this->sendEmailToUser($mentorId, $reminders);
        }
        
    }

    private function sendEmailToUser($mentorId, $reminders){
        $user = \App\User::find($mentorId);
        Mail::to($user)->send(new MentorEmailReminder($reminders));
    }
}
```

This is my email file.

MentorEmailReminder.php

```
    <?php

namespace Modules\User\Emails;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MentorEmailReminder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $reminders;
    public function __construct($reminders)
    {
        $this->reminders = $reminders;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $subject = 'Reminder: Mentoring Session with';
        return $this->from(setting_item("email_from_address"), 'Uplyrn')->subject($subject)->view('User::emails.mentor-email-reminder')->with([
            'reminders' => $this->reminders,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Are you sending email from your local?

Comment: do you use laravel 8 ? sometimes swift mail got problem in production server, it is recommended to upgrade to laravel 9. and don't forget to configure your mail host, username and password in .env